# How to get firebase pushID in onwrite event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-datastore

How to get the push ID?

I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
purchaseTransaction: {
    xxxxxx: {
      amount: 1000,
      user: yyyyyyy
    }
}
```

and when this purchaseTransaction document is updated, I would like to get the pushID (this is generated by firebase)?

```
exports.addPurchaseTransactionToUser = functions.database.ref('/purchaseTransaction/{pushId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const snapshot = change.after;
  const val = snapshot.val();
  console.log('val',val);

  // How to get the pushID?

});
```

Comment: reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation on handling event data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data):

> ```
> exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
>     .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
>       // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
>       const original = snapshot.val();
>       console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
> ```

So in your case the push ID will be available as `context.params.pushId`.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen, I'm a little confuse with snapshot and context. In some samples, there's only snapshot after onCreate and there's no context. Another thing I'm not clear is {pushId} vs {uid}

Comment: My best guess is that those are samples from the pre-v1.0 version of the Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK. On your second concern: the name between `{}` is just the variable name you give to that segment of the path. So the actual name doesn't really matter, as long as it matches in the path string and your code. `pushID` is typically used for path segments generated by `push()` and `uid` is typically used for path segments generated by `user.uid`.

Comment: You are very helpful and knowledgeable. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your code, use `context.params.pushId`.

Comment: Thanks Doug Stevenson. I'll try it out.